# Xamarin: is there a way to inject environment variables into the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Tags: xamarin, gradle, xamarin.android

I've got an open source Xamarin project which has an API key in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. At the moment, I've dealt with that issue by `.gitignore`-ing `AndroidManifest.xml`, but that's a messy solution and it stops me using an automated build environment like AppCenter.

It can be done with a Gradle file: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables

However, in Xamarin we don't have access to Gradle. I can't find a way to do this is in a Xamarin project. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I would use an Xamarin.Android/C# assembly level attribute in its own source file to define the key to be included/merged in the manifest

Comment: https://github.com/dansiegel/Mobile.BuildTools may help too.

Comment: That looks like a very useful one, Jon.

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm facing the same type of issue, but I'm not quite following what you're suggesting. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately environment variables are not available when AndroidManifest.xml (or Info.plist for iOS builds) is being read.

One way I've found of changing configuration values in those files, including the com identifier is to run pre-build scripts via Project Options -> Build -> Custom Commands.

[image: Project options view]

The actual scripts can be very simple. Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat ./manifest/prod/AndroidManifest.xml > Properties/AndroidManifest.xml
```

You'll need a different version of the script for each build configuration. In my case I need to vary the com identifier based on environment in order to isolate production vs development push notifications from Pushy.me.

This shows up in your .csproj file like this:

```
<CustomCommands>
    <CustomCommands>
    <Command>
        <type>BeforeBuild</type>
        <command>set_manifest_dev.sh</command>
        <workingdir>${ProjectDir}</workingdir>
    </Command>
    </CustomCommands>
</CustomCommands>
```