# Xamarin Azure B2C MSAL Authentication - Changing ClientId/ApplicationId At Runtime

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

we have different dev, stage, and production environment, using Adure AD B2C for authentication with MSAL - how can we change the Client ID at runtime in the iOS project's Info.plist and the Android project's AndroidManifest.xml to different application/client IDs depending on which environment we want the app to use?  Or, is there a different way to accomplish when authenticating?  (i.e. creating the URL w/ client ID programmatically).  Thank you

```
    <array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.yourcompany.appname</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>msalxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b215f6a8b57d</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.heska.resultsmobileapp">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:label="Heska.Rma.ResultsMobileApp.Droid" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">
        <activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="msalxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b215f6a8b57d" android:host="auth" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You could have a try with @lemessur's answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54006515/xamarin-is-there-a-way-to-inject-environment-variables-into-the-androidmanifest/58944266#58944266

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT thank you for the reply but that is still at compile time, not runtime... any other options?

Comment: You could use an azure pipeline task to unpack the ipa, update the plist, repack and resign.

Comment: thanks but still not runtime.  want testers and dev to be able to pick dev, test, or prod environment from password protected settings screen in app.